# get-adprincipalgroupmembership not showing all groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Viewing 'Member Of' tab in AD gui for a specific user shows multiple groups. Running `get-adprincipalgroupmembership "username"` returns only one group "Domain Users".

- Affected user is a new user
- Experiencing same issue with another new user
- Able to "discover" same groups from another user through powershell
- Security is identical on all users and groups

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How new is this user? Could this just be a replication issue between the DC PowerShell and your AD are talking to? Have you tried using `get-adprincipalgroupmembership -server sameDCasAD -identity "username"` and maybe you get a different response?

Comment: One user is an hour old and one is a week old. Single DC, so don't think it's a replication issue.  Tried assigning "-server" with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I've got this exact issue, in Windows 2016 AD.

I was able to see the groups in the GUI but not using get-adprincipalgroupmembership.

It was solved by running the command as Administrator, so it looks to me like a permissions issue.